# How to set different user for each mercurial repository?

Tags: iis-7, mercurial

I install mercurial repository on IIS7 (use cgi). I have two different repos and I want to share the rights for each repository. How do I do? My hgweb.config

```
[paths]
/ = c:\repos\*
[web]
allow_push = user1
push_ssl = true
allow_archive = gz bz2 zip
style = paper
```

Comment: I removed the option "allow_push" with hgweb.config and identified it as a file "hgrc" specific repository. Are there other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the `[web]` section in each individual repository’s `.hg/hgrc` file. This way you can specify repository-specific users, style, description, etc.